# Polymer - Vulcanize core-elements and paper elements to one file?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

What would be the best way to concatenate core-elements and paper elements from Polymer? As one large file? two seperate ones (core & paper)? a smaller division (5+ or 10 + or 20+)?

Im trying to reduce the number of imports per web page for a web-app and cant decide how to go about organizing polymer web-component imports. Any advice? / best way to use Vulcanization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to vulcanize everything together. Add core-elements + paper-elements in one import that your index.html use:

elements.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="core-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-elements.html">
```

Then:

```
vulcanize elements.html -o elements.vulcanize.html --csp --inline --strip
```

For Polymer 1.0, you'll need the latest version of vulcanize and the flags have changed a bit: https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize/releases

Comment: Is there a reason to vulcanize all core and paper elements instead of only those you use in your app?

Comment: Yes, you should only vulcanize the elements your app is using. Presumably elements.html only has those. However, the question was about vulcanizing all of the core and paper elements, together.